# ui-route works weird juste the first time angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i have a problem, The first time I press my button every works fine but when I close the modal and I want to re-press the button(open me) , It does not work anymore

where is the problem ?

this is my route

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$qProvider){    
      $stateProvider

          .state("connexion", {
              url: "/",
               views: {

                // for column two, we'll define a separate controller
                'Principal': {

                    abstract :true,
                   templateUrl: 'connexion.html'

                }
               }

          })

          .state('agenda', {

            url: "/agenda",
            views: {

                // for column two, we'll define a separate controller
                'Principal': {

                    abstract :true,
                   // templateUrl: 'agenda.html'
                    template:'<a ui-sref="view">Open me!</a>'


                }
            }


        })
        .state('modal', {
        abstract: true,
        parent: 'agenda',
        url: '/modal',
        onEnter: ['$uibModal', '$state', function($uibModal, $state) {
            $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
            ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            resolve: {

            }
          })
        }]
      })
      .state('view', {
        url: ':id1',
        parent: 'modal',
        views: {
          'modal@': {
            template: '<div class="navbar">'+
                          '<div class="navbar-inner">'+
                          '<h4 class="brand">Quick Start</h4>'+
                          '<ul class="nav">'+
                          '<li><a ui-sref="foo">Route 1</a></li>'+
                          '<li><a ui-sref="bar">Route 2</a></li>'+
                          '</ul>'+
                          '</div>'+
                          '</div>'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('foo', {
        url: ':id2',
        parent: 'modal',
        views: {
          'modal@': {
            template: '<h1>foo</h1><a ui-sref="view">back menu</a>'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('bar', {
        url: ':id3',
        parent: 'modal',
        views: {
          'modal@': {
            template: '<h1>bar</h1><a ui-sref="view">back menu</a>'
          }
        }
      })

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
       $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);

    })
```

and this is a plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/4D6fsQv0FiPqtjoNiebS?p=preview

if someone can help me

thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to change your location when modal closes, ui-sref is probably still pointing to the modal so when you click again, nothing happens

Comment: Hi. Why button ok and close not work ? try fix it and when click use $state.go('agenda')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This had two issues.

1. You were not having a reference to controller in your modal template. Which is why the buttons `Ok` and `Cancel` don't work! So, using the `controllerAs` syntax,

   ```
   $uibModal.open({
     animation: true,
     ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
     ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
     templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
     controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
     controllerAs: '$ctrl',
     resolve: {}
   })
   ```
2. You were remaining in the same state of `modal` even after closing it. Fixed that by following,

   ```
   $ctrl.ok = function() {
     alert(2)
     $uibModalInstance.close();
     $state.go("agenda");
   };

   $ctrl.cancel = function() {
     $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
     $state.go("agenda");
   };
   ```

**Edit**: In order to cover all kinds of `modal` close and visit `agenda` state, you can make use of `modalInstance.closed.then`. Like this:

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    ...
})

modalInstance.closed.then(function() {
    $state.go("agenda")
})
```

You can remove the `$state.go` from the `$ctrl.ok` and `cancel` buttons.

[**updated working plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/I4zCuxdMWOVqExk7tM9b?p=preview)

Comment: I'd say you copied my answer but you had it first

Comment: thanks sir but , this is the only solution ? because in my real program has 2000 result in a ng repeat, I do not want to reload the page, and secondly when I click outside the modal it does not work because I do not do state.go

Comment: Edit sorry but state.go don't refresh the page :D perfect , but there is  just the probleme when i close the modal when i click outside

Comment: @Gazano updated answer with that. should work while clicking outside too now :)

Comment: @Gazano glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues. One was that you didn't have controllerAs syntax going in your modal. This meant that when your "Ok" button in the modal was clicked, the ok function wasn't firing.

The second issue was that you weren't reverting your route back from "agenda/modal" back to "agenda" when closing the modal. So when you clicked, "Open me!" again, it was just staying on "agenda/modal/", and no route change was taking place to trigger the modal's "onEnter".

http://plnkr.co/edit/KyyUS6Y5lwVRr2fYfxNq?p=preview
To fix it I wired up the controllerAs like this

```
 onEnter: ['$uibModal', '$state', function($uibModal, $state) {
        $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
        ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        resolve: {

        }
```

and then had the buttons change the route back like this

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()" ui-sref="agenda">OK</button>
 <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()" ui-sref="agenda">Cancel</button>
```